# mysql create federated all table in database or federated database

Tags: mysql, federated, federated-table

I want to federated all tables from database or federated database.

Can I do that in mysql?

The thing is, I have mysql events at night in server A but for some reason that events weren't finished yet in the morning (It should finished).

So, to make the events faster I want to split the events into other server and that will process some events in server A and some events in server B.

Since, my data is only updated in server A (primary), then I should federated the table from server A to Server B so the server B can process some of the events and give the data back to the server A.

I've tried one federated table and it works, but can I just federated the database or all the tables in a fast or easier way beside create federated table one by one?

Anyone can help me?

Thanks I really appreciate that.

Comment: Please add further information what you want to do and what you tried so far. You just want to copy tables from one db to the other?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for MySQL Clustering: http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/

Comment: maybe, I dont really sure about mysql cluster since it is not free right? Can I just make a federated table but to all table not one by one?